# Shopify: selecting alternate Template for "All Products" page

Tags: shopify, liquid, alternate

I am trying to customise my debut theme and am a bit stuck.

I am trying to create an alternate template for the template that shows all my products.

I am able to create an alternate `collections.liquid` and it also shows up in the admin an it all works fine. But my confusion is, this seems to be the same template for rendering the all my products (not just the products from that collection) too, but how/where select the alternate template for that in the admin?

In other words I am attempting to change the template for `collections/all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `collections/all` uses the `collection.liquid` file.

As you said you can create a new template `collection.custom.liquid` that you can use.

The interesting part is that there is no actual `collection/all` page in the admin. This is the default page that ALL shopify shops have (similar to the homepage/404/cart page). So you don't have access to it from the admin panel by default.

In order to change the ALL collection page you need to create it yourself. Go to your collections admin page and create a new collection with the handle `all` and this will overwrite the default `all` collection and you will be able to choose a different template for it.

---

TLDR; create a new "all" collection in the admin panel and choose the custom template for it.

Answer (score 0):

you have check here collection type grid or list which is enabled from the theme option

```
collection-template.liquid file that show collection/all item list
```

if want to change the alternative template goto the template directory. page.collection_list.liquid